# How to gather the key from Answering side using Twilio TwiML?

Tags: java, xml, twilio, twilio-twiml

I think the title of question is meaningless. Let me explain you situation here:

1) I called on `Twilio Broker bumber`.

2) `Twilio` transferred the call  to given number using the following code.

```
#callToRN.XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     <Response>     
       <Play>https://kaar-ma.com/1.wav</Play>
       <Dial action = "_actionURL">442-333-xxxx</Dial> 
     </Response>
</xml>
```

This connect the given number i.e. `442-333-xxxx`. Now i want to add a new feature in my application i.e.:

```
a) Someone picked the call.
b) He started to talk the caller.
c) Now he/she can transferred the call to  another four-five person simultaneously after pressing "#" key.
d) Or he/she can satisfy the caller and end the call.
```

To capture this situation i called another `TwiML` with the following code in `Java`:

```
TwilioEnum reqst= TwilioEnum.valueOf(reqst);
    try {
        switch (reqst) {
        case hunting:
            output = CallHunting(request);
            break;
```

and i replaced the `_actionURL` in  `<Dial action = "_actionURL">442-333-xxxx</Dial>` with `baseURL + TwilioEnum.hunting` where `baseURL` is the URL to which `Twilio` responds in `#callToRN.XML`.

Definition of `hunting` method is following:

```
hunting(){
  FileBase = "/twilio.CallToAll.xml";
  output = readFile(FileBase );
  return output
}
```

Now please tell me What should i make some changes in `CallToAll.xml` TwiML file so that it allows me to do `a,b and c` points?

```
#CallToAll.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Response>     
  <Play>https://kaar-ma.com/1.wav</Play>
<Dial>4x2-xxx-7271</Dial>
<Dial>4x2-xxx-7271</Dial>
.....
</Response>
```

Please suggest me a solution.

PS: All `Twilio Configuration` is correct because calling/Ending process is working fine with the application.